# Check if image is valid for showing

Tags: php

I am trying to check if the link that the user have enter is a valid image. I tried to do that by using the function `getimagesize()`, and then if the function throws an error, then it's not a valid image.

For some reason, the try-catch statement does not work. I tried to to use the function `file_exist()` as well, but when I enter a normal image link, it says it is not a valid image. How can I fix this?

Attempt 1:

```
if ($link and file_exists($link))
{
    echo "valid image!"
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
$link = $_POST['link'];
try
{
    getimagesize($link);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "worng image! enter again link.";
}
```

Comment: In your `if` clause add an `isset` check, not just `$link`; so `if(isset($link) ... )`

Answer (score 3):

Not all functions in PHP generate an Exception. Many of them, including `getimagesize`, generate an error. The documentation will tell you in the "return value" and "errors/exceptions" section: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Instead, you should check the return value of `getimagesize` - if it's `FALSE`, then it failed. Otherwise you'll get an array.

Answer (score 1):

Using getimagesize for this purpose is not recommended. This is from the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php):

> **Caution**
>   This function expects filename to be a valid image file. If a non-image file is supplied, it may be incorrectly detected as an image and the function will return successfully, but the array may contain nonsensical values.
>   **Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the [Fileinfo](https://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) extension instead**.